# CSS3 transitions in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, css-transitions

I need help with making my code work for IE8 and 9.

This is what i have,

```
$("#logo").delay(1000).animate({
    "margin-top": "-=180px"
}, {
    step: function (now, fx) {
        angle += 2;
        $(this).css({
            "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + angle + "deg)",
            "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + angle + "deg)",
            "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + angle + "deg)",
            "-o-transform": "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"
        });
    },
    duration: 610
},
"linear");
```

but it only works in FF and Chrome.  Any way to make it work in IE?

Comment: Not supported in IE8 http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: For IE9 be sure to use latest jQuery, i think there was a bug in some previous version that didn't like vendor prefixes, not really sure though

Comment: I do  have latest jquery, doesn't make difference for IE. is there any work around?

Comment: It should at least work in IE9. The fallback for IE8 would be to use normal animations without css3 transforms ..though for rotate i dont think you can do that ..just move up/down/right/left/opacity/colors/etc

Comment: Do I need to set any special css property for IE, other that I have now in the code in order to make it work?

Comment: you are missing `"transform": "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"` at the end of the whole css block, I believe IE9 uses unprefixed transforms and transitions, but I am not positive. Anyway, you should still have it because some browsers support the unprefixed.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not make any difference even in IE9...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it , using  plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/,

Worked for me in IE7,8 and 9, as well as Chrome and FF